# DC Motor giving poor output waveform - how do I fix?

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge

I am trying to make a DC motor controller with an H-bridge and PWM powered. The circuit diagram for the motor controller is:

[image: circuit diagram]

The inputs can obviously only be on 1 at a time to prevent short circuit. I am connecting the motor across where the two open circuit nodes, and if I measure the voltage across these two nodes without any motor connected the output is basically just the 5V PWM signal amplified to 12V - which is what I want. The problem arises when I connect the motor across:

[image: oscilloscope output]

Yellow curve is the input, blue curve is the motor output. As it can be seen, it is somewhat okay when the input is HIGH, but when the input is LOW, the voltage across the motor is zero for a little while, and after a bit of time it is then non-zero, even though the input is 0. Should be noted that the other input is grounded. Does anyone have any idea on how to mitigate or remove this non-zero period where it should be zero? Thanks

Comment: Is that the same in the other direction?  It really looks like the bridge is staying half on.

Comment: Let me try and set it up again and I'll post the picture. Do you mean if I ground input 1 and try input 2 instead?

Comment: It seems to do the same

Comment: What about with a resistive load instead of a motor, what is the waveform then?  What about with no input, does it stay at 50% across the motor?  You might just be looking at the CEMF of the motor.

Comment: Tried both a 10k and 470k instead of motor, it outputs the amplified squarewave too (http://imgur.com/QrrBG7I). With no input at all, the output is 0. I did think I was having some EMF action going on, but is there any way to counteract or mitigate it?

Comment: No, CEMF is a necessary and desired part of the operation of a DC motor.  When you are not actively applying power to the motor, it is acting as a generator if it is still rotating.  When you are applying power to the motor, the CEMF is what limits the current to what is needed to drive the load.  Without it, you would be dropping FL amps.

Comment: True, but then why does it drop to 0V right after the square wave input stops, and then after a small time it rises back up to a steady voltage (as you mentioned, it seems to be half-on) - if I decrease frequency, would it allow the voltage to eventually settle to 0V?

Comment: The YELLOW trace, is that going to Input1 or Input2. Also what is the other input being strobed with?  the inverse of the PWM or held HIGH/LOW ?

Comment: Yellow trace is input 1 and input 2 is held low.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that the "0V" portion is not really 0V but actually -0.7V (you can see on the image it is somewhere below 0V, check the scope setup to be sure) and that is the back-EMF spike from the motor's inductance turning on the MOSFET's body diode.

V = -L * dI / dT

As the body diode limits the voltage (a good thing, it could be a few hundred volts otherwise, and destroy the transistors!) the pulse width lasts until the current has fallen to 0. This pulse width will depend on the motor inductance and the current; it probably increases as you load the motor.

Then, with both transistors off, you see the voltage generated by the motor. The only way to eliminate this is to stop the motor - it is proportional to speed. So again, as you load the motor you will slow it, and see the reduction in generated voltage.

You could even sample this voltage during the PWM "off" period to measure the actual motor speed.

The initial peak and decay on the "high" portion of the waveform is again related to the motor's inductance - when the MOSFETs first turn on, the inductance presents a high impedance, so the supply is lightly loaded and the voltage across the motor is high. As the motor current increases, the voltage drops.

If you can see this peak and decay on the incoming power supply, you can improve performance by adding decoupling or using a lower impedance PSU. If you can't, that suggests some voltage is being dropped across the MOSFETs, and you can improve performance using FETs with lower ON resistance.

Answer (score 0):

When it is not connected to a motor the output voltage is ok,but when it is connecting to a motor the voltage drop means,the motor is not getting required current.
So change mosfets to higher current ratings.

Comment: PMOS is rated at 2.8A (http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/12cf/0900766b812cfa37.pdf)
NMOS is rated at 16A (http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00002501.pdf)

Motor is currently not loaded, but is rated at 0.6A under full load (http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-geared-motors/4095232/)

Comment: @Martin: Does that mean that you're actually using PMOS on top instead of NMOS as drawn?  As drawn, the motor would only get (12V - Vgs) instead of the full 12V and those two transistors would get pretty hot.  NMOS all around can certainly work, but not like that.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs to the bipolar transistors are reversed. I'm assuming everything is n channel and npn. when each bipolar transistor turn on, in your schematic, the mosfet it's controling turns off. unless the top 2 mosfets are p channel, then it should work and I can't help.